# easysoap promise ReferenceError: error is not defined

Tags: node.js, soap

I installed easysoap but get this reference error

> /Users/frank/Documents/NodeJs/node_modules/easysoap/node_modules/promise/index.js:82
>         throw err
>               ^ ReferenceError: error is not defined
>       at /Users/frank/Documents/NodeJs/node_modules/easysoap/lib/easysoap.js:90:60
>       at Object._onImmediate (/Users/frank/Documents/NodeJs/node_modules/easysoap/node_modules/promise/core.js:34:15)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)

Is this caused by a mistake i did make, or is anyone else also getting this error?
Is there any documantation on the web?

Comment: this bug is fixed now. sry my fault :P

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug on `easysoap`'s side to me. From [the source code](https://github.com/moszeed/easysoap/blob/master/lib/easysoap.js#L89-L91):

```
request.get(params, this.opts)
.done(function(data) {
   // ...
}, function(err) {
    that.emit('error', 'fail to get wsdl', error);
});
```

The `error` variable indeed doesn't exist, and should have been `err`. You should report this bug to `easysoap`'s maintainer.